# how to ask for different permissions in facebook , api mrt:facebook-sdk meteor-angular

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using mrt:facebook-sdk package with meteor js and angular for facebook api, I am trying to access user friends who are accessing this app so I have asked for some permission like this  :

```
 FB.init({
            appId      : appId,
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            secret: secret,
            requestPermissions: ['user_friends','read_friendlists', 'read_mailbox']
        });
```

but while Login with facebook ,  it ask for public profile only and also, getting empty friendlist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: I have not found answer of my question in that question

Comment: the answer is: as you can read in the docs, you can only get friends who authorized your app too - that is why you are getting an empty list of friends. and read_friendlists is not what you want to use, i assume. also, read_mailbox is deprecated since a very long time. also, read about login review in the docs. and i am not sure what you want to do with "requestPermissions" - where did you get that code from? that parameter does not even exist according to the docs.

Comment: this may help you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/